# R dplyr - Filter unique row in each group with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this

```
id     col2     col3    flag    val
1       a         q 
1       a         w        1
1       b         r    
2       c         q        1      5
2       c         q
2       c         q        1      6
```

I only want these rows

```
id    col2      col3     flag    val
1       a         q 
1       a         w        1  
1       b         r    
2       c         q        1      5
```

Basically the first 3 columns determine a `group`. For each `group`, if there is only 1 observation/row, then keep that row no matter what value of `flag` is. If each `group` has more than 1 observation/row, then keep the first row in that `group` that has `flag` equal 1. I wonder whether there is any way to do this in R with dplyr

Comment: What happens when there are two rows, both with no flag?

Comment: BTW, are those strings (`""` and `"1"`) or numbers (`NA` and `1`)? Your data is not clean (or clear), it would be better please to include the output from `dput(x)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(flag) %>%
  group_by(id, col2, col3) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(rn) %>%
  select(-rn)
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#      id col2  col3   flag   val
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
# 1     1 a     q        NA    NA
# 2     1 a     w         1    NA
# 3     1 b     r        NA    NA
# 4     2 c     q         1     5
```

If your data is instead strings with empty strings (it's not clear in the question), then

```r
dat %>%
  # this is just to transform my number-based 'flag'/'val' to strings, you don't need this
  mutate(across(c(flag, val), ~ if_else(is.na(.), "", as.character(.)))) %>%
  # pick up here
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(!nzchar(flag)) %>%       # this is the only difference from above
  group_by(id, col2, col3) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(rn) %>%
  select(-rn)
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#      id col2  col3  flag  val  
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 a     q     ""    ""   
# 2     1 a     w     "1"   ""   
# 3     1 b     r     ""    ""   
# 4     2 c     q     "1"   "5"
```

The use of `rn` is merely to ensure that the order is preserved across the filtering. If order is not an issue (perhaps it's inferred some other way), then you can remove the `mutate`, and the trailing `arrange(rn) %>% select(-rn)`.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), col2 = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"), col3 = c("q", "w", "r", "q", "q", "q"), flag = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), val = c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr::distinct` helps with exactly this, and the `.keep_all` flag keeps the other columns like in your output.

```
my_data %>%
  distinct(id, col2, col3, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id col2  col3   flag   val
  <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
1     1 a     q        NA    NA
2     1 a     w         1    NA
3     1 b     r        NA    NA
4     2 c     q         1     5
```

Data

```
my_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~col2, ~col3, ~flag, ~val,
   1L,   "a",   "q",    NA,   NA,
   1L,   "a",   "w",    1L,   NA,
   1L,   "b",   "r",    NA,   NA,
   2L,   "c",   "q",    1L,   5L,
   2L,   "c",   "q",    NA,   NA,
   2L,   "c",   "q",    1L,   6L
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select a row when :

1. there is only one row in the group OR
2. the 1st row where `flag = 1` in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, col2, col3) %>%
  filter(n() == 1 | row_number() == match(1, flag)) %>%
  ungroup()

#     id col2  col3   flag   val
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
#1     1 a     q        NA    NA
#2     1 a     w         1    NA
#3     1 b     r        NA    NA
#4     2 c     q         1     5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), col2 = c("a", 
"a", "b", "c", "c", "c"), col3 = c("q", "w", "r", "q", "q", "q"
), flag = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), val = c(NA, NA, NA, 5L, 
NA, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```